# Convert one format into datetime format

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is my `DataFrame`:

```
issue,received_time
aa,25-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
bb,25-06-15 08:42:43.830000000 PM
```

I need output like:

```
issue,received_time
aa,25-06-15
bb,25-06-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['received_time'] = df['received_time'].dt.date
print df
  issue received_time
0    aa    2015-06-25
1    bb    2015-06-25
```

If type of column is not `datetime`, first convert it by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['received_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_time']).dt.date
print df
  issue received_time
0    aa    2015-06-25
1    bb    2015-06-25
```